What is the name of this soccer/football skill by Aitana Bonmatí?
Please watch this video.
What is the name of the first skill she does where she uses the sole of her left foot to drag the ball across her body. Seems like an alternate version of the Cruyff turn because she doesn't move the body behind her but to the front.
Sorry, I'm not great with the names of these moves and I wanna look more into it which is why I need the name.

please include a screenshot from the video showing the skill in action. I have no idea which of the people in that video is the player you mention. Questions should not require people to go watch something on another site.
